# error calling model from controller invoked with AJAX in PHP-MVC

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm calling the MVC controller using AJAX

**AJAX  / view**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#u').change(function(){

        $('#u option:selected').each(function(){
            id_region = $('#u').val();
            
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: './Controllers/controllerTitles.php',
                data: {'data': id_region},
                success: function(data,status){                          
                    alert(data + " " +  status)
                }
            });


        });
        
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php 




class controllerTitles{



    public static function Academic($id_u){

            $d = array("id_u" => $id_u);

            $of=MvcModelT::consultA($d);

            $html = "<option value='0'>SELECT ONE</option>";
     
            foreach($ofs as $o){

                $html .= "<option value='".$o["id_of"]."'>".$o["name"]."</option>";

            }

            echo $html;             
            
        }


}



if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $a = $_POST['data'];
        $menu1 = new controllerTitles();
        $menu1 -> Academic($_POST['data']);

 
}



?>
```

actually this works fine BUT  fatal error happens when calling the model, at this line:

```
$of=MvcModelT::consultA($d);
```

***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MvcModelT" not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\MVC_proyect\Controllers\controllerTitles.php:29***

if I call the Model using "traditional" method this works with any problem, I mean

**VIEW**

```
<?php
    $menu = new controllerTitles();
    $menu -> Academic(234);
?>
```

**CONTROLLER**  is the same as before

I don't know why model not work if controller is called from AJAX

Comment: Where is the require_once to load the model file?  With PHP files need to explicitly load their library files, it isn't like C++ where a compiler + linker combines everything into an executable file

Comment: @DaveS actually I do in the index.php that call all the template.php   as I mention this work fine if I don't use AJAX, but actually I need

Comment: if the AJAX is not calling index.php then none of its code is included when the server gets the request.  If you HTTP GET foo.php then foo.php must have any require_once lines that it needs.  It does not know about any other PHP code unless you require it

Comment: PHP server pages all act like separate applications by default they are not automatically one shared app.    If you used a framework it would add the needed require_once lines at the top of each page to make it work as a unified app.  Also you need to use a PHP session object and update it if you want persistent data on the server side.